# C# Simple Checksum Issue

Tags: c#, checksum

Trying to calculate the checksum of data received from a vendor specific device.

The data received from the device I am reading correctly through serial, but the checksum part is not working. The data received from the device is shown as HEX

The explanation of the required checksum is shown below:

[image]

A sample readout from the console:

[image]

Byte0 = 59, Byte1 = 59, Byte2 = DA, Byte3 = 00, Byte4 = 00, Byte5 = 00, Byte6 = 00 ,Byte7 = 00, Byte8 = 8C

In my code example below, I cannot get the result of 8C and unsure why? (I'm getting 33 instead)

```
public void RS232PortRun(
        IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory,
        CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        //_serialPort.PortName = portName;
        //_serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
        //_serialPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity);
        //_serialPort.DataBits = int.Parse(dataBits.ToUpperInvariant());
        //_serialPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopBits, true);
        //_serialPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), flowControl, true);
        _serialPort.PortName = "COM8";
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        _serialPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "1", true);
        //_serialPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), "None", true);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort.Open();
                cancelToken.Register(_serialPort.Close);
                SerialPortConnected = true;

                var byteArray = new byte[9];

                while (SerialPortConnected == true & !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                    {
                        byteArray[i] = (byte)_serialPort.ReadByte();
                        Console.WriteLine(byteArray[i].ToString("X2"));
                    }

                    // Checksum
                    byte byteArraySum =
                    (byte)(byteArray[0] +
                    (byte)byteArray[2] +
                    (byte)byteArray[3] +
                    (byte)byteArray[4] +
                    (byte)byteArray[5] +
                    (byte)byteArray[6] +
                    (byte)byteArray[7]);

                    var checksum = (byteArraySum & 0xff);

                    Console.WriteLine("Checksum = " + checksum.ToString("X2"));

                    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested == true)
                    {
                        break; // Break from the loop and close the connection.
                    }
                }
                // Once the reading loop has completed or a cancellation token is requested, close the connection.
                _serialPort.Close();
                SerialPortConnected = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }, CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

Comment: The byte's you are adding do not represent the bytes the documentation says. You are adding bytes; 0,2,3,4,5,6,7 but it seems you should be adding bytes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. No?

Comment: Hi, The way I read the document, it says Byte0 + Byte2 + and so on, they didnt mention Byte1 and I already tried this :(

Comment: Damn, sorry, I checked again, so basically the document was written poorly.

Comment: They are lying to you.  Their checksum includes byte 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methodology I used was in fact correct, the manufacturer had not written their document correctly and in fact, Byte1 was required in the checksum, contrary to how it reads. Sorry if wasted anyone's time reading this...

Comment: It's not a waste of time. This is a good reminder that sometimes the documentation isn't right. It's helpful to keep it mind.